# c# having a property field for an abstract class with a generic type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dynamic, abstract-class

So I'm trying to store an object with a generic type that inherits from a base abstract class.  Bellow are the some class definition.

```c#
public abstract class BaseModel<T> {
        //dose some serialization things for building a save file 
}
    
public abstract class StatusEffectLogicModel<T> : BaseModel<StatusEffectLogicModel<T>{
      //dose some delegate and event things

}
//Actual implementations of the Status Effect model
public class TauntStatusEffectLogic : StatusEffectLogicModel<TauntStatusEffectLogic> {
        //Dose Taunt Specific things
}
public class RallyStatusEffectLogic : StatusEffectLogicModel<RallyStatusEffectLogic> { 
        //Dose Rally Specific things
}

//Where I'm having issues
public class CharacterModel : BaseModel<CharacterModel> {
    
        //this is what I need Help with how can i have a property that is of an unknown generic 
    
        public StatusEffectLogicModel activeStatusEffect;
}
```

The closest solution i think i've found is to use a [dynamic property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) but I'm not sure i fully grasp the implications of using this, is this really the best way to achieve what I'm looking for? I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: Adding `public StatusEffectLogicModel<dynamic> activeStatusEffect;` is fine here as you don't know the type, it bypasses the type check.

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize you could put the dynamic there i thought i had to do 'public dynamic activeStatusEffect'.  this makes me feel better

Comment: You are mixing a few things. You don't need dynamic there. A simple object would be sufficient. When you want to do something on activeStatusEffect, you need to provide the member names, methods etc at compile time anyway.  Rather, simply cast the object to the expected type. HOWEVER, my hunch is that you could do with some basic redesign by making the base class non-generic.

Comment: If you don't know anything about the type of `T` at compile time, what good is it? What do you plan to _do_ with `T` if you don't know what type it is? That will determine whether or not `dynamic`, `object`, or something else is appropriate here.